# Add the values inside (labels) together that are inside (list view)

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I add the values inside the labels created in (List View) together?

And show the values added together in a label

```
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Plural" runat="server" Text="0">
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can just bind the list view, and then loop each row, and get the total.

Say I have this listview:

```
    <h2>Fighter Prints</h2>
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td><asp:Label ID="Fighter" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Fighter") %>'  /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="Engine" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Engine") %>'    /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="Thrust" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Thrust") %>'    /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="Description" runat="server" Text = '<%#Eval("Description") %>'   /></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Image ID="iPreview" runat="server" Height="68px" Width="149px" 
                        ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>'/>
                </td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="Qty" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Qty") %>' Width="30px"/></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="Price" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:c2}",Eval("Price")) %>'/></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="Total" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:c2}",Eval("Total")) %>'/></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
           <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server"  style="" class="table table-hover">
               <tbody>
                <tr runat="server" style="" >
                    <th runat="server">Fighter</th>
                    <th runat="server">Engine</th>
                    <th runat="server">Thrust (lbs)</th>
                    <th runat="server">Description</th>
                    <th runat="server">Preview</th>
                    <th runat="server">Qty</th>
                    <th runat="server">Price</th>
                    <th runat="server">Total</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
               </tbody>
                 <tfoot>
                     <tr>
                         <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Total</td>
                     <td><asp:Label ID="MyTotal" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>                             
                     </tr>
                </tfoot>
        </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

Now, in above, I did put in a total footer, but it could have been any control or lable on the page that I stuff the results into.

So, the code to do this?

Bind the ListView

Loop the total, and then put the value into a label, text box, or in this case a label at the footer of the list view.

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Fighters ", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable("Fighters");
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                rstData.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(decimal),"[Qty] * [Price]");
                ListView1.DataSource = rstData;
                ListView1.DataBind();

                decimal myTotal = 0;
                foreach (ListViewItem OneRow in ListView1.Items)
                {
                    Label MyPrice = OneRow.FindControl("Total") as Label;
                    myTotal += Decimal.Parse(MyPrice.Text, NumberStyles.Currency);
                }
                // now update the final total label
                Label lblTotal = ListView1.FindControl("MyTotal") as Label;
                lblTotal.Text = string.Format("{0:c2}", myTotal);
            }
        }
    }
```

Results:

[image]